# Docker is overriding my default route configuration

Tags: docker, networking, raspberry-pi, debian, armbian

A noob here starting with docker in a Orange Pi 3 (Rasberry Pi clone).

I'm trying to configure and start a docker containter (bitwarden_rs), but when I do, I lost connection to the external network. Docker mess with my route table.

**Network configuration:** I have a bridge br0 that bridges eth0 and wlan0.
(Eth0 connects to the router, wlan0 is configured in AP mode)

Table when container is stopped:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    425    0        0 br0  <---OK
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     425    0        0 br0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     425    0        0 br0
```

Table when container is running (No internet access to the exterior)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     205    0        0 docker0 <---NOT OK
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    425    0        0 br0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     205    0        0 docker0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     230    0        0 vethed140ce
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     425    0        0 br0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     425    0        0 br0
```

What can I do to fix it? It's docker config problem or maybe my system problem (armbian).
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

On ubuntu 20.04, I tried many methods,
like prevent [dhcpd to update route](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182967/can-i-prevent-a-default-route-being-added-when-bringing-up-an-interface)
or [change NetworkManager configure to let network-manager to igonre veth* device](https://superuser.com/questions/1428829/docker-is-creatting-another-default-network-route-overriding-default-one-and-dis)
Neither of the above works.

I spent a lot of time and found that connman service changes default route. Change its config file /etc/connman/main.conf by uncommenting following line:

```
#NetworkInterfaceBlacklist = vmnet,vboxnet,virbr,ifb,veth-,vb-
```

and

```
systemctl restart connman
```

to restart connman service.  The issue resolved eventually.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, and this fixed it. Before starting a container, if I ran `ip route get 1.1.1.1` I would get `1.1.1.1 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.0.10 uid 1000` and then after starting the container, in less than a minute it became `1.1.1.1 dev vethe44ad92 src 169.254.157.82 uid 1000` right as all other hosts became unreachable. The arch wiki [specifically mentions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ConnMan#Blacklist_interfaces) the `connman` network interface blacklist, which is by default commented out in the configuration.

Comment: In my case, with a Debian 12 distro, with an LXDE desktop environment, "connman service" effectively interfered with the docker daemon. The docker daemon configuration used was the default one. (`/etc/docker/daemon.json` file does not exist in my host)

In my case only this line was necessary: `NetworkInterfaceBlacklist = veth`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer with `"bip": "172.200.0.1/16"` is wrong, subnet 172.200.0.1/16 is not local, it is wild internet. See any whois service, e.g. https://browserleaks.com/ip/172.200.0.1

Comment: This can better be submitted as a "Comment" to the "Answer" you're referring to.

Answer (score -1):

This is because, as you can see docker creates a linux bridge named 'docker0'.
You can change the default settings for the docker bridge to resolve the issue.
Configure the default bridge network by providing the bip option along with the desired subnet in the daemon.json

```
# vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "bip": "172.200.0.1/16"
}
```

and restart the service.

```
 systemctl restart docker
```

More details [HERE](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-configure-the-default-bridge-docker0-network-for-docker-engine-to-a-different-subnet) and [HERE](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-change-the-default-ip-address-of-docker-bridge/)